# How to find lowest number in an array and return that array's primary index?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like the following.  I'd like to find the array with the lowest number in the "diff" index.  So in this case, I would want to get back array [7].  All I need is the array number (i.e. 7) not any other info.

I know I can use array_column to easily find the lowest number, but how do I also return the overall array index of 7?

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [qb] => 7
            [rb] => 58
            [wr] => 91
            [te] => 3
            [def] => 11
            [diff] => 136
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [qb] => 21
            [rb] => 96
            [wr] => 102
            [te] => 48
            [def] => 15
            [diff] => 240
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [qb] => 23
            [rb] => 86
            [wr] => 216
            [te] => 6
            [def] => 32
            [diff] => 287
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [qb] => 30
            [rb] => 51
            [wr] => 200
            [te] => 14
            [def] => 17
            [diff] => 266
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [qb] => 17
            [rb] => 118
            [wr] => 273
            [te] => 14
            [def] => 30
            [diff] => 380
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [qb] => 10
            [rb] => 112
            [wr] => 142
            [te] => 16
            [def] => 4
            [diff] => 264
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [qb] => 2
            [rb] => 50
            [wr] => 135
            [te] => 9
            [def] => 20
            [diff] => 104
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [qb] => 16
            [rb] => 68
            [wr] => 141
            [te] => 12
            [def] => 1
            [diff] => 224
        )
```

Comment: have you tried looping and comparing...?

Answer (score 5):

As you said you can use array_column and min().
Then use array_search to find the position the min value is in.

```
//Since the array starts with key 1 then use array_values to reset the array first.
$array = array_values($array);
$diff = array_column($array, "diff");
$min = min($diff);
$key = array_search($min, $diff);

$result = $array[$key];
```

Working example:
https://3v4l.org/ci70K

Comment: You should change it `array_search($min, $diff);`

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm thanks! I keep getting confused with PHP not being consistent with the order on functions.

Comment: Your solution is very good, I forgot about `array_search` : ))

Comment: I haven't looked at yours before. Our answers are very similar. Mine does the serach in the back, and yours in a loop in "front". But it's the same code.

Comment: So my actual array has 32 arrays in it.  Array 20 has the lowest 'diff' value but your code returns '19'. Am I missing something maybe with arrays starting count at 0?  That must explain it

Comment: @user3304303 Yes, the arrays starting from 0, you should read about them :)

Comment: Will do. I just expected it to give me the literal primary key rather than the position in the array.  But I can just add 1 to the result :)

Comment: It does give you the literal key. I don't understand how it does not.

Comment: Added array_values to the code to handle arrays that starts with key other than 0.

Answer (score 3):

Here is example, i'm tried to implement solution without loop, but without success:

```
$diffs = array_column($array, 'diff'); // get all diffs
$key = min($diffs); // takes the smallest
$result = '';
foreach ($array as $subarray) {
    if ($subarray['diff'] == $key) { 
        $result = $subarray;
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Where `$array` is your array

**Return:**

```
array(6) {
  ["qb"]=>
  int(2)
  ["rb"]=>
  int(50)
  ["wr"]=>
  int(135)
  ["te"]=>
  int(9)
  ["def"]=>
  int(20)
  ["diff"]=>
  int(104)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use [uasort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) to maintain the index association and use [key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) to  return the index of the current array position.

```
uasort($arrays, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a["diff"] > $b["diff"];
});

echo key($arrays); // 7
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/kZK1Q)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Your PHP demo seems to work but I am confused by something.  If $diff is set to 0 initially, how will any $array['diff'] be less than 0 (since all the 'diff' indexes are way higher than 0)?

Answer (score 0):

You may run into issues if you have multiple minimal 'diff's.
The following loops through the array and builds a map between the original key and the diff value.

min is then used to find the lowest diff value.

We then search for the keys that correspond to that value.  And filter the original array by those keys.

```
<?php

$data =
[
    'five' => [
        'diff'=>5
    ],
    'three' => [
        'diff'=>3
    ],
    'seven' => [
        'diff'=>3
    ]
];

foreach($data as $key => $value)
    $diffs[$key] = $value['diff'];

$min_diff_keys = array_keys($diffs, min($diffs));

$output = array_intersect_key($data, array_flip($min_diff_keys));
var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'three' => 
  array (
    'diff' => 3,
  ),
  'seven' => 
  array (
    'diff' => 3,
  ),
)
```

If you are sure there will only be one unique minimum value of diff, you can use array_search instead of array_keys on the diff map ($diffs), to pull back the relevant key.  And use that index to target your desired array.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for the pot (**PHP 7.3+**). I've no idea how efficient it is.

```
$diffs = array_column($array, "diff");
// lowest first sort (asort maintains correlation with original indices) 
asort($diffs);  
$lowest_dif_key = array_key_first($diffs) + 1;  // requires PHP 7.3
//  as array indices start at zero we have to add one for the correct "array key"
```

Answer (score 0):

This question deserves to an answer that is flexible enough to handle "ties" for the lowest diff and with a computational complexity of *n*.  There is no need to do multiple loop or multiple iterating function calls; and sorting techniques are tie-ignorant.

A single foreach loop with a condition block is simple, efficient, and easy to read.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kZ1J7))

```
$result = ['lowest' => null, 'indexes' => []];
foreach ($array as $index => $row) {
    if ($result['lowest'] === null || $row['diff'] < $result['lowest']) {
        $result['lowest'] = $row['diff'];            // overwrite
        $result['indexes'] = [$index];               // overwrite
    } elseif ($row['diff'] == $result['lowest']) {
        $result['indexes'][] = $index;               // push
    }
}
echo "First level index(es) with the lowest diff: " . implode(', ', $result['indexes']) . "\n";
echo "Lowest occurring diff in data set: " . $result['lowest'];
```

Output:

```
First level index(es) with the lowest diff: 7
Lowest occurring diff in data set: 104
```